# Why does this foreign key using inheritance not work?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

```
create table abstract_addresses (
  address_id int primary key
);

create table phone_numbers (
  phone_number text not null unique
) inherits (abstract_addresses) ;

create table contacts (
  name text primary key,
  address_id int not null references abstract_addresses(address_id)
);

insert into phone_numbers values (1, '18005551212'); --works

select * from abstract_addresses;

address_id
1

select * from phone_numbers;

address_id  phone_number
1           18005551212


insert into contacts values ('Neil', 1); --error
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "contacts" violates foreign key constraint "contacts_address_id_fkey"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (address_id)=(1) is not present in table "abstract_addresses".
```

Just a bad use-case for postgresql table inheritance?

Comment: The phone number insert works because you didn't create a foreign key on phone_numbers to abstract_addresses.

Comment: @GriffeyDog, after the insert into phone_numbers, abstract_addresses has a value of 1 in its address_id .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the caveats in the docs:

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html

To do what you want:

1. Create a table with only an id — like you did.
2. Don't use inheritance. Really don't. It's useful to partition log tables; not for what you're doing.
3. Make phone number ids default to `nextval('abstract_addresses_address_id_seq')`, or whatever the sequence name is.
4. Add a foreign key in `phone_numbers` referencing `abstract_addresses (address_id)`. Make it deferrable, initially deferred.
5. Add an after insert trigger on `phone_numbers` that inserts a new row in `abstract_addresses` when needed.
6. If appropriate, add an after delete trigger on `phone_numbers` that cascade deletes `abstract_addresses` — make sure it occurs ***after*** the delete, else affected rows will report incorrect values when you delete from `phone_numbers`.

That way, you'll have an `abstract_address` for use in occasional tables that need such a thing, while still being able to have a hard reference to `phone_numbers` where the latter is what you actually want.

One caveat to be aware of: it doesn't play well with ORMs.